# How to enforce types within object while letting key be "fixed" in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object in a project that I'm trying to type:

```
export const dateFormat = {
  hourOnly: { hour: 'numeric' }
  …
}
```

I know that the values in this object should fit `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions` so I tried:

```
export const dateFormat: {[key: string]: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions} = {
  hourOnly: { hour: 'numeric' }
  …
}
```

This works but I lose the ability to get auto complete for this object elsewhere in the project. I tried adding `as const` at the end, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to enforce an objects values while still getting auto-complete for the keys?

I also tried:

```
type dateFormatOptions = 'hourOnly'

export const dateFormat: {[key: dateFormatOptions]: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions} = {
  hourOnly: { hour: 'numeric' }
  …
}
```

but in this case typescript says the index signature should be a string or a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the keys you can just use `Record` to create a type that has those explicit keys of the type you want (`Record` is called a mapped type)

```
type dateFormatOptions = 'hourOnly'

export const dateFormat: Record<dateFormatOptions, Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions> = {
  hourOnly: { hour: 'numeric' }
}
```

This does require you to keep the names of the properties in two places. Another option is to use a function with a constrained generic type parameter. The type parameter constraint will keep all values of the specified type but the actual keys will be inferred based on the object you pass in.

```
function createDateFormatOptions<K extends PropertyKey>(o: Record<K, Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions>): Record<K, Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions> {
    return o;
}
export const dateFormat = createDateFormatOptions({
  hourOnly: { hour: 'numeric' },
})
```